# Python: Why does copying the function name to a local namespace result in a faster access

Tags: python

From the code here: https://www.learnsteps.com/increasing-performance-python-code/

```
import datetime 
alist = [str(x) for x in range(100000000)]

print("\nStandard loop.") 
a = datetime.datetime.now() 
result = [] 
for item in alist: 
    result.append(len(item)) 
b = datetime.datetime.now() 
print((b-a).total_seconds()) 

print("\nStandard loop with function name in local namespace.") 
a = datetime.datetime.now() 
result = [] 
fn = len 
for item in alist:
    result.append(fn(item))
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print((b-a).total_seconds())

print("\nUsing map.")
a = datetime.datetime.now()
result = list(map(len, alist))
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print((b-a).total_seconds())

print("\nUsing map with function name in local namespace.")
a = datetime.datetime.now() 
fn = len 
result = list(map(fn, alist)) 
b = datetime.datetime.now() 
print((b-a).total_seconds()) 

print("\nList comprehension.") 
a = datetime.datetime.now() 
result = [len(i) for i in alist] 
b = datetime.datetime.now() 
print((b-a).total_seconds()) 
print("\nList comprehension with name in local namespace.") 

a = datetime.datetime.now() 
fn = len 
result = [fn(i) for i in alist] 
b = datetime.datetime.now() 
print((b-a).total_seconds())
```

which produces this output:

```
Standard loop.
20.862797

Standard loop with function name in local namespace.
16.34087

Using map.
6.893764

Using map with function name in local namespace.
6.774654

List comprehension.
9.362831

List comprehension with name in local namespace.
10.007393
```

Can someone provide a better explanation than 'function lookups are costly' as to why creating a function prototype close to the use of the function is somehow faster?
(This doesn't work for most functions, and usually only in tight loops, but why does this happen at all?)

Comment: You aren't using local namespaces anywhere, as far as I can tell. Only global and builtins. Anyway, what you are seeing here is the effect of searching for a name in globals vs builtins. Essentially, you have a hash to check the global namespace (a literal `dict`) and then if that fails, it checks builtins. This explains the minor differences. I don't really believe your differences in the `map` are real, you should really be using the `timeit` module for these sorts of tests.

Comment: Now, if you really *did* move things into a local namespace (i.e. a function), you'd see significant effects. Because local namespace's are optimized to array lookups vs dictionary hashing. Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045396/where-does-the-performance-boost-of-map-or-list-comprehension-implementations-ov/39046254#39046254

Comment: I find it interesting that the post in the question advocates for this @azazelspeaks. While making a global variable from a builtin is _technically_ a way to optimize performance, as far as I have ever seen the more common (and cost-effective) optimization is to bring globals into a function's local scope for tightly-bound loops.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/48421303/7954504.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because name resolution starts from the local namespace first, and if it is not found locally, it would then be looked up in the next nearest enclosing code block, and then its next nearest enclosing code block, until the module code block, which is the global namespace, and if the name isn't found in the global namespace, then and only then will the interpreter look up the built-in names. This is why assigning the reference to the built-in name `len` to a global name `fn` would speed up the name resolution in your code example.

Comment: There is no assignment to a local namespace here

Comment: I'm talking about the resolution order in general, but you're right that `fn` is really a global name in this case. Edited accordingly then. Thanks.

Comment: So you're saying if I did the same things but in functions I'd get even better speed improvements by using those local function names? Why don't more people use this then?

Comment: @azazelspeaks Most people use functions. Some people will assign a global name to a local name in a hot loop, but the differences are marginal. One case where you *can* get slightly more significant speed-ups is assigning the result of a method lookup to a local name if you are going to reuse that method in a loop, like `append = my_list.append` most of the time these micro optimizations are simply not necessary